# "undefined class" Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, class

I recently started programming in C ++ and am having some difficulties in relation to the exchange of data between classes.
I searched many tutorials and examples, but none worked. I finally decided to ask for help because I do not know what do ...

PS: I want to call **keyPressEvent** function from my B (solEditor) class

thanks.

**addons/soleditor.h (class)**

```
#include <Qsci/qsciscintilla.h>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class Editor; // main class
class solEditor : public QsciScintilla
{

public:
    explicit solEditor(QWidget *parent = 0);
    Editor editor; // error << 

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);

};
```

**editor.h (main window)**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "about.h"
#include "data.h"
#include "addons/codeeditor.h"
#include "addons/highlighter.h"
#include "addons/soleditor.h"
#include "plugins/headergenerator.h"
#include "plugins/updatescreen.h"

namespace Ui {
class Editor;
}

class solEditor;

class Editor : public QMainWindow
{

    Q_OBJECT

solEditor *sE;

public:
    QsciScintilla* ce;
    Highlighter *Hl;
    solEditor *e;
    Ui::Editor *ui;
    explicit Editor(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Editor();

public slots:
    void on_KeyPress(QKeyEvent *e);

};
```

**Error:**

> > SOLEditor\addons\soleditor.h:14: error: C2079: 'solEditor::editor' uses undefined class 'Editor'

Comment: Why do you open the namespace `Ui` in `"editor.h"` and forward-declare `Ui::Editor` there? Also, why the forward-declaration for the class `solEditor` in the same file?

Comment: Are you sure `Editor` should be a member-object of `solEditor`, and that shouldn't be a simple pointer?

Comment: `Ui::Editor *ui` was generated by qtcreator. Now I removed the `solEditor`, that was not being used. (sorry for my english)

Comment: I want to call `on_KeyPress` function from my `solEditor` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a forward declaration

```
class Editor; // main class
```

with a local instance of that class

```
Editor editor; // error <<
```

Unfortunately, that is not possible, as in this case the compiler needs to know the full details of the `Editor` class.
There are two possible solutions:

1. Make the member a  pointer: `Editor* editor`
2. Use an `#include` instead of a forward declaration.

If you want to make your code flexible, you could do it like this:

```
class solEditor : public QsciScintilla
{

public:
    explicit solEditor(Editor* editor, QWidget* parent = 0);

    inline Editor* editor() const { return _editor; }

private:
    Editor* _editor;
}
```

and in the cpp file:

```
solEditor::solEditor(Editor* editor, QWidget* parent)
    // TODO: call parent constructor
{
    _editor = editor;
}

solEditor::~solEditor()
{
    _editor = NULL;
}
```

You can then create a `solEditor` instance like this:

```
QWidget* optionalParentWidget = GetParentWidgetFromSomewhere();
Editor* editor = GetEditorInstanceFromSomewhere(); // or create it yourself

solEditor* myEditor = new solEditor(editor, optionalParentWidget);
```

(As a side node, classes in C++ usually start with a capital letter: `QWidget, Editor, SolEditor`. That makes it easier to spot if something is a class, a function or a variable).

---

About the key press event: If you want one class to handle certain events of another class, it's best to use the `eventFilter` mechanism:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Comment: Thanks! (installEventFilter also helped me)